# How to perform multiple fetches using the github api which depend on each other and return data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, github, es6-promise

I am trying to get data from the github api and return the data in a route. However, when I try and send the data back to the client , the projects array is empty.

I have tried returning the data in the second last promise but it isnt working. Would this require using Promises / async/await

```
router.get('/projects', (req, res) => {

    fetchRepos().then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Server Error'
            })
            return
        }
        return res.json()
    }).then(repos => {
        var projects = []

        repos.forEach(element => {
            fetch(element.languages_url + '?access_token=' + process.env.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN).then(res => res.json()).then(langs => {
                langs = Object.keys(langs).map(e => e.toLowerCase())
                projects.push({
                    title: element.name,
                    description: element.description,
                    link: element.html_url,
                    technologies: langs,
                    id: element.pushed_at,
                    webpage: element.homepage
                })
                 console.log(projects)

            })

        });
        console.log(projects)
        res.send({
            success:true,
            data:projects
        })
    })

});
```

Comment: use Promise.all() to turn many promises into one, then your array will be populated by the time the all()'s _then_ fires.

Comment: I wouldnt be able to put all of the promises together because the languages api url depends on the intial fetch from the api that happens at the beginning

Comment: You can simply move the first promise into the other, it's just an if condition anyways that only gets triggered on an error case

Comment: @Deiv ? how can the first promise be moved int other other when the second one depends on it

Comment: Because you're just chaining the promise, you can directly use the .join result without doing so